# why does this java string not cause an compiler error?

Tags: java, string, macos, unicode, macos-ventura

I was trying to use unicode to insert quotes around the "world" in a java hello world program.
I forgot to save it and it just worked anyway. I'm just super confused about this.

I use a MacBook Pro with macOS Ventura 13.2.1, and openJDK 19.0.1.

This is the code that I ran.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, \u0022 + "world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `\u022` == `"`. What you have is equivalent to `"Hello, " + "world!"` (i.e., concatenating two strings).